# When are root's SSH keys generated?

Tags: redhat, kickstart, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen, anaconda

I have hosts with and without keys in /root/.ssh.  I've noticed before some on screen feedback for SSH key generation on start up (first time.)  But I am not sure what the catalyst is.  I have looked in /root/anaconda-ks.cfg and don't see anything different that could lead to this.

What was chosen/enabled for the servers that do versus the ones that do not?

Note: I know I can do it manually -- I am just looking to understand when / how it is inconsistently generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are confusing it with host keys.

Host keys are generated on first boot. (Well, or when the ssh server starts the first time).

The directory `/root/.ssh` is created when you first use ssh (the client). It stores the known_hosts file here (containing the public keys of hosts your have been connected before).

One can use `ssh-keygen` to create public/private keypair (it is name /root/.ssh/id_rsa and /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub per default).

Comment: No, it's not host keys.  I am looking at hosts with /root/.ssh/id_dsa /root/.ssh/id_dsa.pub that I am confident that no one has ran ssh-keygen on.  I think Setup Agent is creating the keys via the firstboot service but can't confirm that with any documentation / URL.  I can test it tomorrow.  I just was hoping that someone in the SF community would know.

Comment: Oh, ok. I am not that familiar with rhel and anaconda. I can think of anaconda generating the keys for some post-install activity, but it can be just my imagination.

Comment: You are exactly right.  Sorry for not understanding what you meant, but I finally found it. What I was seeing on first boot was the do_*_keygen routines from sshd's init script. (/etc/rc.d/init.d/sshd) It checks for the existence of /etc/ssh_host_key, /etc/ssh_host_rsa_key, and /etc/ssh_host_dsa_key and creates them as necessary. 

Seems I had made an incorrect correlation that lead me to think it was root user's keys, not host keys. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Im 100% sure, you are talking about the keys when openssh-server is installed..

On basically every unix system, this happens **on first boot** after installation..
Regardless Im not sure i have ever seen a server without SSH..

Hope this helps.. :D

Comment: For what reason vote me down??
My answer is absolutely correct..

Comment: No idea.  I hate it when people do that without explanation.  It's not correct in this case entirely but not worthy of a down vote.